# Converting an Excel list according to row indexes

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert a list in Excel VBA as follows:

My original list in the one colored in grey. It shows a sequence. 
I want to generate the list on the right according to each number location.

[image: sample list and output]

For example:
`3` is **second** in the left list so `2` is on the **third** location in the right list;
`6` is **fourth** in the left list so `4` is on the **sixth** location in the right list ...

I tried using 'For' loops in VBA, but it's getting a bit long and complex, is there a way to do it by using arrays in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, just set the first, last and ranges as needed.

```
Private Sub cbSort_Click()

Dim wArray As Variant, dArray As Variant
Dim first As Integer, last As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

first = 1
last = 8

Set wArray = Range("A" & first & ":A" & last)
ReDim dArray(1 To last - first + 1, 1 To 1)

j = 1
For i = first To last
  dArray(wArray(i, 1), 1) = j
  j = j + 1
Next i

Range("B" & first & ":B" & last) = dArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

A formula can easily achieve this. Assuming data is in A1:A8, in B1 and copied down:

```
=MATCH(ROW(),A$1:A$8,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim source As Range
    On Error GoTo ErrTransformIt
    Set source = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Source", Type:=8)
    TransformIt source
    Exit Sub
ErrTransformIt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub TransformIt(ByVal source As Range)
    Dim target As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstRow As Long

    firstRow = source(1).Row
    i = 1

    For Each c In source.Cells
        Set target = ActiveSheet.Cells(firstRow + c.Value - 1, c.Column + 1)
        If target.Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Target is already used by [" & target.Value & "]", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        target.Value = i
        i = i + 1
    Next c
End Sub
```